# Scale-out Node.js with Socket.io on Windows Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-roles

I followed the ["Build a Node.js Chat Application..."](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-chat-app-socketio/) post which shows step by step how to deploy Node.js application with Socket.io to provide real-time chat webapp.

The only thing missing is showing how to scale-out this application, as I found scaling such application on Windows Azure is not that simple since Azure LB only supports Round-robin policy.

I did find [socket.io-servicebus](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/socket.io-servicebus) which provides some solution for the need of pub/sub store. 
But that is not enough since Socket.io has a known bug in the handshake phase [#952](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/952), which means the handshake phase can't work without sticky session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not tried this.

Going back the the first release where node was supported in cloud services. I would often run node in a worker role instead of a web role in order to avoid iisnode. This was necessary back then because Windows Server 2008 R2 did not support websockets at all. So in order to use socket.io with node, that was the approach. Now that Windows Server 2012 is available, we don't do that anymore.

Given that, there are tools for osfamily 2 ([SessionAffinity](https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/SessionAffinity)) and osfamily 3 ([SessionAffinity4](https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/SessionAffinity4)) to enable sticky sessions in a worker role (explicitly not web role). That could meet your need at the cost of a bit more complexity around deployment and local testing (if you use the emulator ).

I do have clients running with SignalR and the Service Bus Backplane running in Windows Azure. So I can validate that set of options. But I have not run the SessionAffinity plugins.

It is also worth noting that Windows Azure WebSites are using ARR to bring in session affinity by default. That is only if you are not bound by some reason to cloud services. ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/18/disabling-arr-s-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, it seems like all these solutions just stick another LB server (with sticky session) between Azure LB and the node.js servers.

Comment: It is definitely not ideal. It is worth noting how much investment is going into Websites these days. Way more features are being added to Websites than Cloud Services. Unless there is a need to install components on the server, I have been adding new clients to Websites over Cloud Services.

Comment: I moved to primus.io over Websockets and it seems to work fine. Since it doesn't have the socket.io racecondition bug